# How to apply a different icon into a cloned feature

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I've implemented a feature which drawn an icon rather than a regular shape, as we can see in the picture below:

[image]

My intention is to add an icon alert beside this feature (and many others features). So, to try achieve this I'm cloning the feature and trying to apply a different image in the style being created, like the code below:

```
export const setIconEffect = (feature: Feature, event: any) => {
    const vectorContext = getVectorContext(event);

    // clone the feature geometry
    const flashGeom = feature.getGeometry().clone();

    // creates a new style to be applied into this cloned feature
    const style = new Style({
        image: new Icon({
            src: 'assets/images/mapElements/warning-icon.png',
            scale: 0.1,
            imgSize: toSize(500),
            anchorOrigin: IconOrigin.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
            anchor: [1.8, 0.05],
        }),
    });
    // set it into the cloned geometry
    vectorContext.setStyle(style);
    vectorContext.drawGeometry(flashGeom);
};
```

The problem is that, when I try to apply a different `src`, it doesn't work, but, if I use the same `src` it does work.

Applying a different `src` it just show the mark as usual.
Applying the same `src` it draws the icon properly, but, as copy (and this is not the purpose). Example below:

[image]

Comment: It might be easier to just apply an array of style to the original feature, containing the main icon and the derived one(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After defining the style, we need to force the loading of the image by doing this:

```
style.getImage().load();
```